# The animal armatures aren't showing up as options. How do I fix this?

Tags: armature, bones

I'm trying to rig an animal, but when I go to Add>Armature only the single bone and human armature show up as options. Rigify is on, and I've tried restarting Blender and my computer several times. How can I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Blender 2.8 for Windows new scene, enable Rigify, Add -> Armiture -> Animals and they are there. What OS, Blender version are you using? If you run Blender from the command line do any error messages come up when enabling Rigify?

Comment: I never considered the version, huh. I was on version 2.7- I updated it to 2.8 and it shows up now! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong version. Updated from 2.7 to 2.8 and that fixed it.